# Вывод данных из базы в виде блоков

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер. Вопрос:

Никак не могу сообразить как правильно написать класс для вывода данных из базы в виде блоков. Есть данные в базе, таблица `PAGES`. В ней есть странички с различными полями. Нужно такие функции написать, чтобы потом из ассоциативного массива можно было выцепить по названиям полей таблицы данные. А сам принцип построения блоков таков: Есть странички, где `PARENT_ID = 0` - это родительские странички, в которые входят подстранички. В блочном меню они являются заголовками перед тремя блоками, в которых уже выводятся дочернии пункты меню.

Пока только у меня получилось вывести все втранички, а сгруппировать их в правильное блочное меню не получается. Любым советам и пожеланиям буду рад.

В запросах к базе главные и дочерние пункты меню отсеял.
У дочерних пунктов `PARENT_I`D равен `ID` родительского элемента.

Answer (score 1):

делаем выборку из бд данных страниц и их родителей с сортировкой по `PARENT_ID, PAGE_ID` `(ORDER BY PARENT_ID, PAGE_ID)`, получаем массив вначале которого будут страницы первого уровня и по наростающей более глубокие уровни. Формируем из него массив (дополнительные поля добавляем по вкусу)- пример получившегося массива:

```
$pages = array (
    array('PAGE_ID' => 1, 'PARENT_ID' => 0),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 2, 'PARENT_ID' => 0),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 3, 'PARENT_ID' => 1),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 4, 'PARENT_ID' => 2),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 5, 'PARENT_ID' => 4),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 6, 'PARENT_ID' => 5),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 7, 'PARENT_ID' => 5),
    array('PAGE_ID' => 8, 'PARENT_ID' => 5)
);
```

начнем обход со страниц более глубокой иерархии, для этого перевернем массив

```
$pages = array_reverse($pages);
```

и пройдемся по нему вытаскивая суб страницы и складывая их в нужном порядке в текущем же массиве:

```
foreach  ($pages as $k => &$p) {
  foreach ($pages as &$page){
    if($page['PAGE_ID'] == $p['PARENT_ID']){
      $page['sub'][] = $p;
      unset($pages[$k]);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

выводим то, что у нас получилось:

```
print_r($pages);
```

видим следующую конструкцию (немного длинновато, но чего только не сделаешь для наглядности :) )

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [PAGE_ID] => 2
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [PAGE_ID] => 4
                            [PARENT_ID] => 2
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PAGE_ID] => 5
                                            [PARENT_ID] => 4
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PAGE_ID] => 8
                                                            [PARENT_ID] => 5
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PAGE_ID] => 7
                                                            [PARENT_ID] => 5
                                                        )
                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [PAGE_ID] => 6
                                                            [PARENT_ID] => 5
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [PAGE_ID] => 1
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [PAGE_ID] => 3
                            [PARENT_ID] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
```

т.е. у нас есть массив с иерархиями, на базе которого вполне можно реализовывать навигацию, генерацию sitemap и тд

PS надеюсь это то, что требовалось

Comment: не много не то, но я по другому реализовал. Сделал выборку из базы родительских пунктов, потом отсеял дочернии и уже в циклах распределял по нужным массивам :)